# Using boost::lambda with boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lambda

I'm having an issue of using lambda within thread on Boost.

The code is supposed to place the result of a function (string) within a specified index of a vector.

```
std::vector< string > results(size);
std::vector< boost::thread > threads;
for(  int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    threads.push_back( boost::thread( results.at( i ) = getAString( x,y,zed ) ) );
}
```

How would I go about using Boost::lambda here?

Please don't mention using c++11 syntax.  The system I'm forced to be working on can't support a compiler that supports c++11.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I'm wondering what the benefit of lambda functions would be. Lambdas in C++ work best for STL algorithms on containers that are already populated. In your case you're looking to populate the vector `results` with a lambda, which isn't the sort of thing intended by the library. You might have an uphill battle.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/lambda.html#introduction

That being said, it is possible to create lambdas that are fed rvalues directly:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.rvalues_as_actual_arguments
Though in your case I'm not sure what the benefit would be over a fixed function that could take the arguments used in composing the string.

Further, I believe that threaded functions cannot return values, so your threaded function is going to have to take the location of `results.at(i)` as an argument.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the lambda into a class extension of boost::thread that took results.at(i), as you mentioned.  Definitely helped a lot, thanks!